# Kafka Messaging in Quarkus Multimaven Containerized Environment

Tags: java, maven, apache-kafka, quarkus

I am currently stuck with the following error message in a multimaven dockerized quarkus project using kafka for messaging:

> Member kafka-consumer-product-out-b9d0f3f0-2b0c-4a0a-8a2c-ba0d58e05d8d sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator kafka:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null) due to consumer poll timeout has expired. This means the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time processing messages. You can address this either by increasing max.poll.interval.ms or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.

First of all, I am really new to kafka and do not really understand the very way it works, thus I am having a bit of trouble working with it. Thank you in advance for the patience.

To give a bit more context, the project contains multiple microservices one of them being  a product-inventory which messages changes products using a kafka sink on to other microservices. Strangely, another microservice correctly suggests the message, while for two others I am getting the described error.

I triple checked all the configurations, especially the ones described in the [quarkus kafka guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/kafka#testing-a-kafka-application), however cannot find an error there. Does someone have a hint on where to search for the error?

Answer (score 1):

You can address this either by increasing max.poll.interval.ms or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records...

This error typically means your processing loop taken too much time while processing the messages it got from poll, you can limit the number of messages you are getting from the poll , make your process handling each message faster, or set higher interval timeout setting between calling poll.

The recommended behavior is having a seperate thread processing the messages and not "hogging" the consuming of the messages if possible for your implementation

Comment: As i said I am totally new to Kafka, but I can hardly believe that it took too much time...
This error message pops up for a single published product change, is it really possible that this takes too much time?